# Errors while making makefile const declaration and struct issues

Tags: c, struct, makefile

I am having issues making a makefile. When I compile I get so many issues. My main problem is figuring out where I should put my global const within my program. I tried putting them all in the main file but that didn't seem to work.

```
banksystem: main.o admin.o customer.o
    gcc -o banksystem main.o admin.o customer.o

main.o: main.c admin.h customer.h
    gcc -c main.c

admin.o: admin.c admin.h basefunctions.h
    gcc -c admin.c

customer.o: customer.c customer.h basefunctions.h
    gcc -c customer.c

basefunctions.o: basefunctions.c basefunctions.h
    gcc -c basefunctions.c
```

This is how I'm making the makefile. I don't really know if it is correct. I made the entire code into one file before doing this to test each function in one spot but now I'm trying to split it up. I am getting a ton of errors with my const and struct

```
struct info{  //Example struct
    int a;
    int b;
};
struct info collection[MAX]; //Example array
```

I don't know which file to put this in as well as the other global const

```
#define MAX 100
#define char "customerdata.txt"
typedef int (*compfn)(const void*, const void*)
```

Should I put these variables in the main source file? Or should I put them in the basefunctions source file, also how should I use extern in the files that don't house the information for my struct or I guess, how exactly do I deal with my struct? All of my functions use it. All of my functions use the array.

The code is quite lengthy so I'm not going to include it. Gist of what I'm asking,

How do I reformat my code to work in a makefile when I have a struct, array of structs, global int const, global char const.

```
void load(){
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb");
        if (fp != NULL){
                fread(collection, sizeof(struct userinfo), MAX, fp);
        }
        else{
                printf("ERROR");
        }
        fclose(fp);
}

void save(){
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "wb");
        fwrite (collection, 1, sizeof(collection), fp);
        fclose(fp);
}
```

I'm also getting this warning with both of these functions

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a 
cast [-Wint-conversion]
     fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb");
                ^
```

Sorry if this is lengthy and vague help would be very much appreciated

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with makefiles - you'd have the same problem *without* a makefile if you just ran all the commands yourself.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have mentioned some of the recommendations regarding globals in header files

You should put all your globals in header file
protect the header file so that it does not get included twice in same object(.o) by adding this at the top

```
#ifndef __MYHEADER__FILE__
#define __MYHEADER__FILE__
#endif
```

Each global variable you declare in your header file(say myheader.h) should be delared  as eg

```
MYEXTERN struct info collection[MAX];
```

If you include ,myheader.h in multiple c files
In any one of the c files(preferrable where main in present) include it as

```
#define MYEXTERN
#include<myheader.h>
```

This ensures collection is declared as struct info collection[MAX]

In rest of C files you should include it as

```
#define MYEXTERN extern
#include<myheader.h>
```

This ensures collection is declared as extern struct info collection[MAX]

Answer (score -1):

```
banksystem: main.o admin.o customer.o
gcc -o banksystem main.o admin.o customer.o
```

I just needed to include `basefunctions.o` here and it compiled and works